# send parameter by reference from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

myJs:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
   $scope.bla = [{firstName: 6},{firstName: 7}];
   $scope.changeNumber = function(num){
     num = 10; 
   }
});
```

myHtml:

```
<div ng-repeat="b in bla" ng-click=changeNumber(b.firstName)>{{b.firstName}}</div>
```

The problem is: the value of `$scope.bla` doesn't change. So, how can i pass the `b` parameter by reference and not by value. 
p.s. of course it's not my code, it's just for an example.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a collection. You need brackets not braces to represent a list/array.

     `$scope.bla = [{firstName: 6},{firstName: 7}];`

Comment: And there are lot of typos in the code. Is that `changeNum` or `changeNumber`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the index of the number clicked to the changeNumber method, and then use the index to change your original object. For example:

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="b in bla" ng-click="changeNumber($index)">{{b.firstName}}</div>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.bla = [{firstName: 6},{firstName: 7}];
    $scope.changeNumber = function(index){
    $scope.bla[index].firstName = 10;
  }
}]);
```

Refer to this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aditiraveesh/ZG9re/5550/).

Comment: The problem is that I'm run recursively on a tree containing parents and children, then there is no meaning to index Because every round of the loop begins again re-index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the object, pass the object (b) itself instead of it's firstName property.